# Need the custom scrollbar in ListView not to get stretched/shrink according to the items

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar

I have used a custom scrollbar for my ListView. I used the following code.

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/bars"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="260dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            android:fadingEdge="none"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
            android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_large1"
            android:scrollingCache="false" />
```

The scrollbar get stretched or shrink according to the amount of items in that ListView. If the item is less, the scrollbar get stretched and looks not good. How can I make the scrollbar image, not depending on the amount the listitem?

Comment: use a nine patch image. for `scrollbar_large1`

Comment: check in your <SDK>/android-sdk/platforms/android-xx/data/res/drawable-mdpi/scrollbar_handle_vertical.9.png try using that.

Comment: @ M Mohsin, I'm already using a nine patch image. Still the scrollbar get stretched/shrink.

Comment: is there any other way to give custom image to the scrollbar.